# Finding attribute from .getNamedItem returns null after parsed xml

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm currently working for the first time with API's and are having some trouble retrieving data.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<schedule>
...
<scheduledepisode>
  <episodeid>22441</episodeid>
  <title>Ekonyheter </title>
  <starttimeutc>2012-09-19T04:00:00Z</starttimeutc>
  <endtimeutc>2012-09-19T04:03:00Z</endtimeutc>
  <program id="83" name="Ekot" />
  <channel id="164" name="P3" />
</scheduledepisode>
<scheduledepisode>
```

So i used `NodeList nodelist1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("scheduledepisode");` to get all the `scheduledepisode` elements, then I thought that to revive the data under title I could simple use the following:

```
System.out.println(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title").getTextContent());
```

However this only returns null and i cant understand why, can someone explain what I am missing here. To my understanding the title element is a attribute to the `scheduledepisode` element. Is that wrong?

The length of the nodelist is correct contra the amount of `scheduledepisodes` so I'm assuming that I have gotten the correct elements.

The code looks like this:

```
NodeList nodelist1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("scheduledepisode");
for (int i = 0; i < nodelist1.getLength(); i++)
{
      Node node = nodelist1.item(i);
      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE )
      {
           if (node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title") != null) {
                 System.out.println(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title").getTextContent());
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `<title>` is an element and not attribute of `<scheduledepisode>`, `getAttributes()` would not work. Therefore, use `getElementsByTagName` again:

```java
NodeList se_nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("scheduledepisode");
for (int i = 0; i < nodelist1.getLength(); i++)
{
      Node node = nodelist1.item(i);
      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE )
      {
           if (node.getElementsByTagName("title") != null) {
                 System.out.println(node.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed to create a new nodelist ```NodeList titles = doc.getElementsBytagName("title");``` and from there pick out a item and get it's title etc etc.